# Conversion of GPS Coordinate units using C

Tags: c, gps, coordinates

I want to write a simple program using C language that converts GPS coordinates between three different notational forms.

What I want the program to do is:
1)Ask the user to enter coordinates in decimal degrees.  After that it should report back the value back in all three forms.

2)Ask the user to enter in degree decimal minute form.  After that it should report back the values in all three forms.

3) Ask the user to enter in degree minute second form. After that it should report back the values in all three forms.

**(this is what I mean by all three formats when reporting back:* 42.87157 degrees is equal to 42 degrees 52.294 minutes, which is also equal to 42 degrees 52 minutes 17.64 seconds.)**

Comment: Is this homework?  Hint: Think about it as a base conversion.  Also think about how you'd convert between 1.1 days to 1 day and x hours...

Answer (score 0):

Rest is left as an exercise:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  double d, m;
  scanf("%lf", &d);
  printf("degree: %lf\n", d); 
  m = (d - (int)d) * 60; 
  printf("degree: %d mins: %lf\n", (int)d, m); 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the lazy one

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  double d, m, s;
  
  scanf("%lf", &d);
  printf("degree: %lf\n", d); 
  m = (d - (int)d) * 60; 
  s = (m - (int)m) * 60; 
  printf("degree: %d mins: %d sec: %.2lf\n", (int)d, (int)m, s); 
  return 0;
}
```